# Terser way of generating deeply nested hash

Tags: ruby

I need to generate a Ruby hash that looks like this:

```
{ "children" => [
  { "children" => [
    { "children" => [
      { "children" => [] }
    ]}
  ]}
]}
```

... for an arbitrary level of nesting.  So far the best I've come up with is:

```
def nested_hash(levels)
  return {} if levels < 1
  root = { 'children' => [] }
  children = root['children']
  (levels - 1).times { children = (children << { 'children' => [] }).first['children'] }
  root
end
```

This doesn't seem particularly terse or elegant.  Can anyone offer suggestions on making this more terse or elegant?

Comment: why do you need arrays with a single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursion perhaps?

```
def nested_hash(levels)
  return if levels <= 0
  { "children" => [ nested_hash(levels - 1) ].compact }
end
```

Or it could be

```
def nested_hash(levels)
  return nil if levels <= 0
  array = nested_hash(levels - 1)
  { "children" => array.nil? ? [] : [array] }
end
```

if you prefer handling the `nil` upfront, instead of removing it with `compact`

In either case, `nested_hash(3)` will get you

```
{"children"=>[
  {"children"=>[
    {"children"=>[]}
  ]}
]}
```

Note that unlike yours, these ones will return `nil` when `levels` is zero or less. So you'll want to do the `{}` fallback elsewhere, e.g. `hsh = nested_hash(x) || {}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def nested_hash(levels)
  return {} if levels < 1
  array = Array.new(levels, "children")
  array.reduce(nil) { |memo, item| { item => [memo].compact } }
end
```

---

### Array.new

`Array.new(levels, "children")` creates a levels-sized Array of "children" Strings.

*Example:*

```
Array.new(3, "foo")
#=> ["foo", "foo", "foo"]
```

---

### reduce

`reduce` (which is an alias for `inject`) iterates over all elements of the Array, and accumulates the result in `memo`. We seed `memo`with `nil`.

*Example:*

The block passed to `reduce` looks like this in the first iteration:

```
{ "children" => [nil].compact }
#=> { "children" => [] }
```

`memo` now holds that result.

The block in the second iteration:

```
{ "children" => [{ "children" => [] }].compact }
#=> { "children" => [{ "children" => [] }] }
```

Comment: I just realized that instead of doing `Array.new(levels, "children"` you could also simply do `array = ["children"] * levels`

Comment: Clever. In super-terse mode: `def nested_hash(levels); levels < 1 ? nil : (["children"] * levels).reduce(nil) { |memo, item| { item => [memo].compact } }; end`

Comment: for me "terse" implies "readability" that's why I've expanded it a little bit

Comment: Of course - by "super-terse" I meant "waaay to compacted to actually be useful"; wasn't being serious about writing code like that

Answer (score 3):

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [Hash.new(&hash.default_proc)] }
```

Not sure if this fits your needs, but this creates a hash that if accessed with #[] and the key doesn't exist, automatically creates that key with the value being an array with 1 element: another hash which behaves identically.

So initially the hash is empty:

```
>> h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [Hash.new(&hash.default_proc)] }
=> {}
```

But will create the required structure when accessed.

```
>> h[:children][0][:children][0][:children]
=> [{}]
>> h
=> {:children=>[{:children=>[{:children=>[{}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's a very neat implementation, but doesn't do what I want (when fed into a recursive parser, it would eventually cause a stack overflow).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Ruby Gem [xkeys](https://rubygems.org/gems/xkeys) which extends the hash to have nesting capabilities:

```
require 'xkeys'

h = {}.extend XKeys::Auto
h['children', 0, 'children', 0, 'children', 0, 'children'] = []
```

OR, maybe you have something like this...

```
path = ['children', 0, 'children', 0, 'children', 0, 'children']
h[*path] = []
```